# C# Hide external dlls

Tags: c#, dll

I have a solution with 2 class library projects: CalcSalaryLib and EmployeeManager.

EmployeeManager uses CalcSalaryLib and therefore has a reference to it.
Also, CalcSalaryLib uses the jint.dll.

I need to provide EmployeeManager.dll to someone else to use it but I don't want to attach CalcSalaryLib.dll to it and I don't want him to use or even see the code inside it.

I read a little about ILMerge but that's not exactly what I looking for. 
I want to simulate a situation as if the methods and classes of CalcSalaryLib were internal within EmployeeManager.

What is the best approach to dealing with such a situation?

Comment: You can obfuscate the code and share the dll in Visual Studio- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040107/Configuring-Visual-Studio-for-Obfuscation

Comment: Or you add a contract only assembly, containing only the interfaces for the CalcSalaryLib. Then the EmployeeManager assembly only references that new contract assembly, but not CalcSalaryLib directly. Have a look at Dependency Injection (DI) and DI containers